# Функция правильного завершения слов при различных событиях

Tags: php

Хотелось бы правильно завершать слова в событиях:
`осталось 26 часов 15 минут 01 секунда`
или
`в течение 26 часов 15 минут 01 секунды`
или
`в течение 21 минуты`

зашел в тупик...

```
function timeWordEnding($digit, $time = 2)
{
    $lastDigit = substr($digit, -1);

    switch ($time)
    {
        case 1:
            $timeW = 'секунд';
        break;
        case 2:
            $timeW = 'минут';
        break;
        case 3:
            $timeW = 'час';
        break;
    }


    if ($lastDigit == 0 || $lastDigit == 5 || $lastDigit == 6 || $lastDigit == 7 || $lastDigit == 8 || $lastDigit == 9)

        $finish = $timeW;

    elseif ($lastDigit == 1)

        $finish = $timeW . 'ы';

    elseif ($lastDigit == 2 || $lastDigit == 3 || $lastDigit == 4)

        $finish = $timeW . 'ы';

    return $digit . ' ' . $finish;
}


echo 'В течение ' . timeWordEnding(51, 1);
```

Передается 2 параметра timeWordEnding(время, тип времени)
Может можно как-то проще сделать и не писать 100 раз ЕСЛИ ЕСЛИ ЕСЛИ...?
Видимо, еще и падежи необходимо будет передавать.
Поддается реализации или черт ногу сломает? И лучше писать: ч. мин. сек.

Comment: Да, да и да. Реализации поддается, черт ногу сломает, лучше писать ч. мин. сек.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
 * Функция возвращает окончание для множественного числа слова на основании числа и массива окончаний
 * @param  $number Integer Число на основе которого нужно сформировать окончание
 * @param  $endingsArray  Array Массив слов или окончаний для чисел (1, 4, 5),
 *         например array('яблоко', 'яблока', 'яблок')
 * @return String
 */
function getNumEnding($number, $endingArray)
{
    $number = $number % 100;
    if ($number>=11 && $number<=19) {
        $ending=$endingArray[2];
    }
    else {
        $i = $number % 10;
        switch ($i)
        {
            case (1): $ending = $endingArray[0]; break;
            case (2):
            case (3):
            case (4): $ending = $endingArray[1]; break;
            default: $ending=$endingArray[2];
        }
    }
    return $ending;
}
$hours = date('H');
$minutes = date('m');
$seconds = date('s');

echo 'Осталось '.$hours.' ' .getNumEnding($hours, array('час', 'часа', 'часов')).' '.
    $minutes . ' ' .getNumEnding($minutes, array('минута', 'минуты', 'минут')).' '.
    $seconds . ' '. getNumEnding($seconds, array('секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд'));
echo '<br>';
echo 'В течение '.$hours.' ' .getNumEnding($hours, array('часа', 'часов', 'часов')).' '.
    $minutes . ' ' .getNumEnding($minutes, array('минуты', 'минут', 'минут')).' '.
    $seconds . ' '. getNumEnding($seconds, array('секунды', 'секунд', 'секунд'));
```

> Осталось 23 часа 09 минут 59 секунд 
>   В течение 23 часов 09 минут 59 секунд

Answer (score 2):

На Хабре были [ф-ии для склонения существительных после числительных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/105428/) на JS и PHP:

```
/**
 * Функция возвращает окончание для множественного числа слова на основании числа и массива окончаний
 * @param  $number Integer Число на основе которого нужно сформировать окончание
 * @param  $endingsArray  Array Массив слов или окончаний для чисел (1, 4, 5),
 *         например array('яблоко', 'яблока', 'яблок')
 * @return String
 */
function getNumEnding($number, $endingArray)
{
    $number = $number % 100;
    if ($number>=11 && $number<=19) {
        $ending=$endingArray[2];
    }
    else {
        $i = $number % 10;
        switch ($i)
        {
            case (1): $ending = $endingArray[0]; break;
            case (2):
            case (3):
            case (4): $ending = $endingArray[1]; break;
            default: $ending=$endingArray[2];
        }
    }
    return $ending;
}
```

Это для склонений. Получаете время в секундах, и выделяете из них часы, минуты и секунды как остатки от деления.

А ещё вы хотите, как я понял, отбрасывать нулевые части. Все случаи:

```
00:00:00 => (Сейчас!)
00:00:05 => 5 секунд
00:21:00 => 21 минута
00:21:05 => 21 минута и 5 секунд
01:00:00 => 1 час
01:00:32 => 1 час и 32 секунды   // точно тут пропускать минуты?
01:21:00 => 1 час и 21 минута
01:21:32 => 1 час, 21 минута и 32 секунды
```

Всего 8 вариантов. Я думаю, разберётесь.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо много условных операторов. В русском языке очень просто, играют только числа 1, 2-4 и для остальных по умолчанию.
На скорую руку

```
function appenText($number, $type) {
    // массив слов
    $textArr = array(
        's' => array('секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд'),
        'm' => array('минута', 'минуты', 'минут'),
        'h' => array('час', 'часа', 'часов'),
        'd' => array('день', 'дня', 'дней'),
        'y' => array('год', 'года', 'лет'),
    );
    $number = (int) $number; // приводим к числу
    $result = $number . ' '; // формируем начало строки
    // проверка на наличие типа в массиве
    if(isset($textArr[$type])) {
        // если число больше 20 то берем остаток от деления на 10
        switch ( ($number >= 20) ? $number % 10 : $number )
        {
            case 1:
                $result .= $textArr[$type][0];
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
                $result .= $textArr[$type][1];
                break;
            default:
                $result .= $textArr[$type][2];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(appenText(5, 's'));
var_dump(appenText(1, 'm'));
var_dump(appenText(23, 'h'));
var_dump(appenText(4, 'd'));
var_dump(appenText(100500, 'y'));
```

Вывод будет такой

```
string(14) "5 секунд"
string(14) "1 минута"
string(11) "23 часа"
string(8) "4 дня"
string(13) "100500 лет"
```

Для своего решения конечно нужно красиво оформить и желательно ООП.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего не решать эту задачу самостоятельно, а воспользоваться уже [готовыми](https://github.com/jimmiw/php-time-ago) [решениями](https://github.com/smirik/php-datetime-ago)