# Улучшение интерфейса. TimePicker

Tags: android, android-sdk, время, интерфейс

```
OnTimeSetListener myCallBack = new OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
          myHour = hourOfDay;
          myMinute = minute;
          if((((myHour >= 5)&&(myHour <= 20)) ||(myHour == 0))||((myMinute == 1)||(myMinute == 21)||(myMinute == 31)||(myMinute == 41)||(myMinute == 51)))
              tvTime.setText("Время: " + myHour + " часов " + myMinute + " минута");
          if((myHour == 2)||(((myHour > 20)&&(myHour <= 24))))
              tvTime.setText("Время: " + myHour + " часа " + myMinute + " minutes");
          if((myHour == 1)||(myHour == 21))
              tvTime.setText("Время: " + myHour + " час " + myMinute + " minutes");
        }
      };
```

Как правильно реализовать различную интерпретацию слов минута/минуты/минут в данном случае?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430528/ - про андроид, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450182/190934 - простой метод, правда на php, но на яве та же идея будет.

Comment: это называется **Plurals**. https://www.google.dk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20plurals&es_th=1