# Как правильно написать падежи после числа?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая в зависимости от последней цифры в числе определяет необходимый падеж:

```
function toCaseCount(arg) {
    let last = arg.toString().split('').pop();
    if(last == 1) return ' рейс'
    else if(last >= 2 && last <= 4) return ' рейса'
    else if(last >= 5 && last <= 9) return ' рейсов'
    else return ' рейсов'
}
```

Итого, если:

- 1 - рейс
- 2-4 - рейса
- 5-9 - рейсов

Но я не учёл того, что моя функция будет возвращать строку не **311 рейсов**, а **311 рейс**. Как это можно элегантно подправить?

Пытался сделать `let last = arg.toString().slice(-2);`, чтобы получить не одну последнюю цифру, а две. И тогда, если число просто 1, то я и получу 1. А если последнее число 8411, то я получу 11. Но тогда не будут работать все предыдущие условия, поскольку при числе 1244 уже будет не одна цифра 4, а две - 44. И эта цифра не попадёт под условие.

Comment: добавь еще 11-19 - рейсов

Comment: @АлексейШиманский потому, что код разбивает строку на массив подстрок, и берёт последний элемент. А последний элемент массива в данном случае - 1. То есть, попадает под условие _если 1 то рейс_

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/708558/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450179/186083

Comment: @Grundy вот помнил же что есть дубликат и были темы, но удивительно, не смог найти

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так ты ж там и отписывался кстати, вот там я с дубликатами как-то не особо понял поэтому не стал дальше цепочку закрывать :) можешь флагнуть как дубликат я прикрою :)

Comment: @Grundy отписывался, да. но я не запоминаю где я что отписывался и когда, поэтому это не в счёт :D ничего флагать не буду)

Comment: @Grundy, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD*) поле для деятельности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function toCaseCount(arg) {
  let titles = ['рейс', 'рейса', 'рейсов'];
  let cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(arg % 100 > 4 && arg % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[Math.min(arg % 10, 5)]];
}

//-------------------------------------//
let testOutputStr = '';
for (let i = 1; i < 1000; ++i) {
  testOutputStr += i + ' ' +toCaseCount(i) + '<br/>';  
}

document.write(testOutputStr);
```