# Проблема с склонениями

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу разобраться, в чем причина.
Имеется код:

```
var count = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML;
console.log('my count', count);
function declination(number, titles) {
cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
return titles[ (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2:cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5] ];
}
title = declination(count, [' штук', ' штуки']);
var summ = count + title;
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = summ;
```

В count получаю число (допустим, сейчас 13).
Выводит 13 и undefined, где ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка в первом условии. В массиве `titles` всего два элемента(индексы `0` и `1`), а т.к. `13%100 == 13` что больше `4` и меньше `20` мы получаем `titles[2]` которого нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам массив `cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]`, в нем присутствует 2, но в массиве `titles` всего 2 элемента (индексы 0 и 1). Так же и с условием `(number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2`

Вам нужно добавить еще 1 элемент вот так `declination(count, [' штукa', ' штуки', ' штук'])`

Вот рабочий код взят [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739088/235964)

```js
var count = 13;
console.log('my count', count);
function declination(arg, titles) {
  let cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(arg % 100 > 4 && arg % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[Math.min(arg % 10, 5)]];
}
title = declination(count, [' штукa', ' штуки', ' штук']);
var summ = count + title;
console.log('summ', summ);
```