# Необходимо помочь в написании кода на Python, позволяющем склонять существительное от числительных по времени, в рамках моего кода и синтаксиса

Tags: python

уважаемые участники форума! Мне требуется помощь в написании кода, который позволил бы определять окончание у существительного от времени одновременно у двух переменных, а именно часов и минут: 1 час 1 минутА, 1 час 2 минутЫ, 2 часа 5 минут, 2 часа 54 минуты, 7 часов 5 минут и так далее.
Ниже прикрепляю свой код в рамках которого нужно дописать необходимое! Заранее спасибо за помощь.

P.S. Понимаю, что на форуме встречаются похожие вопросы, но часть из них не по Питону, а та часть, что по питону - не дает нормального ответа конкретно по моему коду:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru') 
t = dt.now()
print(f'Сегодня {t:%d %B %Y (%A)}') 
print(f'Сейчас {t:%H час. %M мин. %S сек.}')
```

Сейчас выводится час. и мин. с точкой, а нужно, чтобы склонялись в зависимости от значений %H и %M :)

Интерпретатор Python 3.8.10

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/903897  Или ручками по аналогии, например, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450179/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85).

Comment: Необходимо кому? Что вам мешает на основе вопросов не по питону и не конкретно по вашему коду самостоятельно доработать ваш код?

Comment: Наверное, отсутствие опыта и знаний, которые отчасти и хотел получить здесь)

Answer (score 3):

```
import humanize
import datetime
humanize.i18n.activate("ru_RU")
print(
humanize.naturaldelta(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1001))
)
#16 минут
```

Исспользовать модуль humanize

Answer (score 1):

Делюсь идеей и алгоритмом. Код писать в ответе не буду, т.к. не увидел в вопросе собственных попыток решить задачу.

Идея - напишите три простые функции (для часов, минут и секунд), которые принимают на вход число и возвращают соответствующее число и единицу в правильной форме.

Например:

- `get_hr_form(21)` -> `21 час`
- `get_hr_form(3)` -> `3 часа`
- `get_hr_form(17)` -> `17 часов`
- тоже самое для минут и секунд

Правильное склонение определяйте по остатку от деления на 10.

Comment: "2 часа" но "12 часов". Десятки тоже влияют, не только единицы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, спасибо за уточнение. Числа от 5 до 19 будут иметь одинаковую форму.

Answer (score 1):

Склонять по-русски легко. Нужны формы для нуля, единицы и двух и процедура которая выбирает нужную форму:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

# число, "0 друзей", "1 друг", "2 друга"
def declension(n, form_0, form_1, form_2):
    units = n % 10
    tens = (n // 10) % 10
    if tens == 1:
        return form_0
    if units in [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
        return form_0
    if units == 1:
        return form_1
    if units in [2, 3, 4]:
        return form_2


def russian_time(t):
    h = declension(t.hour, 'часов', 'час', 'часа')
    m = declension(t.minute, 'минут', 'минута', 'минуты')
    s = declension(t.second, 'секунд', 'секунда', 'секунды')
    return f'{t.hour} {h} {t.minute} {m} {t.second} {s}'


print(russian_time(dt.now()))
```

> ```
> $ python russian_clock.py
> 2 часа 31 минута 37 секунд
> ```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода [`make_agree_with_number`](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/guide.html#id8) ("согласовать с числом") из [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pymorphy2

t = dt.now()
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
hour_word = morph.parse("час")[0]
minute_word = morph.parse("минута")[0]
second_word = morph.parse("секунда")[0]


def make_agree_with_number(unit, number):
    """
    Вспомогательная функция, которая согласовывает слово с числом,
    и возвращает число вместе с этим словом
    """
    return "{} {}".format(number, unit.make_agree_with_number(number).word)


print("Сейчас {} {} {}".format(
    make_agree_with_number(hour_word, t.hour),
    make_agree_with_number(minute_word, t.minute),
    make_agree_with_number(second_word, t.second)
))
```

Пример вывода:

```
Сейчас 8 часов 26 минут 23 секунды
```